# PHP file returns right echo, but writes the wrong string in database

Tags: php, database, compare, contacts

I'm having the weirdest problem right now. In order to see if a contact is already in the database I check it. For me to see I echo: "Is in database" or "is not in database". For the user to see I return him the string with the same massage. Weird thing is, the echo is always right, but the string is always the same "Is not in database", even when a contact is in database. For example: I add my Mum. My Mum is in database, so the echo is correct and says "Is in database". But the string I get returned always says "Is not in database".

Full code

```
<?php
    $DB_HostName = "localhost";
    $DB_Name = "db";
    $DB_User = "user";
    $DB_Pass = "pw";
    $DB_Table = "contacts";

    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die (mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

    $fnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["fnumber"]);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $DB_Table WHERE User = '$fnumber'", $con);

    if ($result) {

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            echo "This user is already in database";

            $number = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["number"]);

            mysql_query("DELETE FROM Echo WHERE Number=('$number')");

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO Echo (Number,Answer)
            VALUES ('$number','This user is already in database.')");
        }

        else echo 
            "This user isn't in the database";

        $number = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["number"]);

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM Echo WHERE Number=('$number')");

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Echo (Number,Answer)
        VALUES ('$number','this user isn't in the database.')");
    }

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

And before you ask: In order to not crowd my database I always delete the number and then write the entry.

Comment: "And before you ask: In order to not crowd my database I always delete the number and then write the entry."

Did you know you can update the data in an existing row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is the right code:

```
if ($result) {

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        echo "This user is already in database";

        $number = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["number"]);

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM Echo WHERE Number=('$number')");

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Echo (Number,Answer)
        VALUES ('$number','This user is already in database.')");

    } else {

            echo "This user isn't in the database";

        $number = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["number"]);

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM Echo WHERE Number=('$number')");

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Echo (Number,Answer)
        VALUES ('$number','this user isn't in the database.')");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Also, `VALUES ('$number','this user isn''t in the database.')");` needs the `'` escaped.

Comment: Thank you very much, lol always the same with me, overlooking brackets or something else that is equally stupid....

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, the string is between double quotes, isn't necessary.

Comment: @mariogl yes you do need to escape the `'`, otherwise it's not a valid SQL query.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't understand why if the `'` is between doble quotes, it has to be escaped. The code works right, maybe is it a standard or is it for seccurity?

Comment: @mariogl it is valid PHP syntax but the query will not execute when sent to SQL: `'this user isn't in the database.'`.

Comment: @CodeCaster I just inserted a register with that code, and there are a lot of examples in the internet (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp).

Comment: @CodeCaster I had executed a similar code, and after your last comment I've executed exactly the code and it works, the row is inserted. Which error should I receive from the database?

Comment: @mariogl you don't have to throw manual pages at me. If you would have executed exactly the code you posted, you would have got _"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use **near 't** in the database.')' at line 1"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not throwing you manual pages, I'm giving you the URLs where I have found the examples with no escaped simple quotes. I don't want to prove anything to someone with much more reputation, I'm only trying to understand.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ok, my fault: I was focusing on starting and ending quotes, not the one in `isn't`... you both are right, my apologies.

Comment: @mariogl: please see the difference between `"INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('Will Work')"` and `"INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('Won't work')"`. Hope it's clear now. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need a second closing } before the

```
else echo "This user isn't in the database";
```

Comment: You need an opening bracket before the `echo` and an additional closing bracket at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

```
else echo 
"This user isn't in the database";

$number = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["number"]);

mysql_query("DELETE FROM Echo WHERE Number=('$number')");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Echo (Number,Answer)
VALUES ('$number','this user isn't in the database.')");
```

The lower three lines will always be executed, since there are no brackets after `else`. The second `mysql_query` will always fail because the ' isn't escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You are not wrapping the entire `else` branch in brackets. That way, everything after the `else echo "This user isn't in the database";' is executed, which overwrites your above data.

The `else` branch should look like:

```
    else
    {  // <-- NEW
        echo "This user isn't in the database";

        $number = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["number"]);

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM Echo WHERE Number=('$number')");

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Echo (Number,Answer)
        VALUES ('$number','this user isn't in the database.')");
    }  // <-- NEW
}
```